# Re-use thread with NSURLSession in swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, nsurlsession

I'm writing a function (in swift 2) which performs an HTTP request every few seconds.
I'm using timer to schedule those requests.

The problem is that each request uses a new thread so after a few minutes I used many many threads (can be hundreds), which was closed right after they finished but I prefer to use one thread that will do this job.

The function is:

```
func getStatus()
{
    let strUrl:String = MY_URL;
    let url = NSURL(string:strUrl);

    let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), );
    var dataTask:NSURLSessionDataTask?

    dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!)
    {
        data, response, error in
        if let error = error
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else if let httpresponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        {
            if httpresponse.statusCode == 200
            {
                self.getDataFromJson(data);
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask?.resume();

    myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(retryInterval,
                                                     target: self,
                                                     selector: #selector(getStatus),
                                                     userInfo: nil,
                                                     repeats: false);
}
```

What is the right way for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to schedule a new timer within the completion handler / closure of the data task, instead of triggering every time `getStatus` has finished (and maybe the data task is still running). So only one data task will be running at a time, something like:

```
// ...
dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!)
{
    data, response, error in
    //... 
    Dispatch.main.async {
        self.myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(retryInterval,
                                                              target: self,
                                                              selector: #selector(getStatus),
                                                              userInfo: nil,
                                                              repeats: false);
    }
}
dataTask?.resume();
// ...
```

Or you could use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + retryInterval) { ... }` instead of the timer.

Comment: Thanks! I print the thread details (NSThread.currentThread()) and the number of the thread is still increment, I want to use always the same thread.... it didn't work :(

Comment: Where do you "print" the thread details? Within the `dataTaskWithURL` closure, or outside (in `getStatus`)?

Comment: Inside the closure right after the "else if let httpresponse = response...". The output is: <NSThread: 0x1702699c0>{number = 17, name = (null)}, and after a few second the number is 18, 19, 20 and so on....

Comment: Well, you could set the `delegateQueue` property, but I'm not sure if it will also be used for execution of the closure you hand in (you'll have to try).

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it with delegateQueue? 
Thanks!